# What is the name for a design element which includes trusses within a member?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I cannot think of what to call this design technique, where a truss-like structure is used within a member to provide strength and rigidity with minimized weight. I’ve included a picture which demonstrates the design element. The structure I am trying to describe is used on the stalks that the forward and reverse pedals are connected to; the stalks have a series of triangles on either side which, I presume, is to reduce weight.

[image]

Comment: I think the answer might be "Ribs".

Comment: adding to what @SamiSafarini said, maybe `reinforcing ribs`

Comment: I believe that’s the term I was looking for, thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Reinforcing ribs does seem to be the answer, not sure why I couldn’t conjure that term!